# jQuery .animate() is jumpy on 1 page but not in another page

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slidetoggle

I am using the following code here:

```
function toggle_visibility(id, h4id)
{
    var e = $("#" + id);
    var h = $("#" + h4id);
    h.css({'padding': '0 0 0 20px'});
    e.animate({height: 'toggle'}, 400, function(){
        var vImg = e.is(':visible') ? 'minus' : 'plus';
        h.css({'background-image': 'url(/images/' + vImg + '.png)'});
    });
}
```

If you take a look at this page here:  http://opportunityfinance.net/industry/
Works fine

If you take a look at this page here:  http://opportunityfinance.net/consulting/default.aspx?id=6474
It's really jumpy animation.  It jumps when you click it to slide down and when you click it to slide up.

I'm trying to determine the difference between the 2 pages that could be causing this, and can't seem to understand why it doesn't slide down or up without the jumps on the 2nd page.

How can I fix this?  Been reading several questions and answers already here at SO with no luck.

Thanks guys, let me know if you need more info on this.

Comment: try content of second page on first page and see what happens.

Comment: This is a live site, I can't just change pages content like that.  Besides, it doesn't matter what content is in it (if you look at the 3rd `<h4>` tag barely any content and still jumps), it is still jumpy on the 2nd page!  There must be something different on the actual page I would assume (like `paddings` or `margins`) that is causing this...?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the complexity of the content inside the divs you're animating open and closed. In your first example, you've got small paragraphs of plain text. In your second example, you've got embedded videos.

You might investigate whether using CSS3-based animations can give you better performance for complex content.

Comment: That can't be true, cause even the 3rd `<h4>` tag entitled, ***Between Production and Retail: Mid-Tier Food Chain Enterprises*** has only text in it, and is still jumpy when you click it.

Comment: The jump you're getting with that h4 is the classic jQuery slide animation bump, unrelated to the poorer performance you're getting with the other elements. http://jqueryfordesigners.com/slidedown-animation-jump-revisited/

Comment: Poorer performance with the other elements??  What do you mean by this?  As far as the slide animation bump goes, so I have to set a height?  Suppose an array of heights than?

Answer (score 0):

It's to do with the height of the content thats being exposed to the best of my knowledge – i.e page one the toggle content is fairly short so the animation speed of 400 is enough to smoothly animate to full height whereas on the second page the rate it expands is a lot quicker + as its taller than the outer content wrapper the jump is happening when the outer wrapper expands to accommodate it.

Best solution that I can think of would be to slow the animation speed down!

Comment: If you click on the ***Update on Final Actions of the 112th Congress Impacting Opportunity Finance*** `<h4>` tag on the 1st page, that is a really big height also, but the slide is still fine, without any jumping.  So, this logic isn't quite right.

Comment: I just now slowed the animation down to 1000 ms (1 second), and still no change!  I doubt that slowing the animation speed down will fix this!

Answer (score 0):

Like Angus said, your problem is that the height of your hidden elements change everytime, but your time to animate no ( 400ms ) .It's that simple. Your problem is that you have the same time for different heights, so try to change your time with a ratio relative to the height.

Comment: I slowed it down to 1000 ms, no good, problem still existed.  Also, if you look at the 3rd `<h4>` tag on that page, it's a 1 LINE sentence that gets revealed when clicking on it, but still jumps.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery SlideUp() and SlideDown() instead of animate(). It will work ...

Comment: Just changed it to use `slideUp` and `slideDown`, but did not help.  Problem still exists.

Comment: You are adding "MARGIN-BOTTOM: 1em" to every parent div.Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was due to the `<h4>` tag having a `margin-bottom` and `margin-top` set to `1em`.  This wasn't really a problem for `margin-top`, since I was setting a 5px margin-top in the `toggle2` class for the `<h4>` element that was overwriting it, but still caused issues.

To fix this, I set both `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` to `0px` and wrapped each `<h4>Title</h4><div>contents</div>` within a `div` tag giving that `div` tag a `margin-bottom` set to `1em`.

This seems to have fixed the problem now!  Thanks, but I had a feeling that the margins and/or padding was causing the issue, and I was right!